# Can't Pull Google Source Repo During Automated Cloud Build

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-container-registry

I have a [`Dockerfile`](https://hub.docker.com/r/chipoglesby/rbaseplus/~/dockerfile/) that I'm using to build an image that will run on Google Compute Engine.

Part of the `Dockerfile` should pull a Google Cloud Source Repo and add it to the image.

I'm getting the error below when using Cloud Builder:

```

```
Step 6/6 : RUN gcloud source repos clone repoXXX --project=projectXXX
---> Running in xxx
[91mERROR: (gcloud.source.repos.clone) You do not currently have an active account selected.
Please run:
  $ gcloud auth login 
    to obtain new credentials, or if you have already logged in with a different account:
  $ gcloud config set account ACCOUNT
    to select an already authenticated account to use.
The command '/bin/sh -c gcloud source repos clone repoXXX -- 
project=projectXXX' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here?

I'm not using a `cloudbuild.yaml` file, but I assumed that the cloudbuilder service account would be able to pull the repo since it has Editor access in IAM.

What should I do to build the image successfully?

**Update:**

If you found this question, I was able to add the Google Cloud Source Repos by building  following the two steps below:

1. Build a `cloudbuild.yaml` file and including the steps below:

`steps:
    # Pull Search Console repo to include in the build.
    - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    args: ['source', 'repos', 'clone', 'xxx']`

2. In your `Dockerfile` you can copy the repo from your workspace into your new image:

`FROM xxx:latest
    # Copy the repo into Docker
    copy xxx /xxx`

You can read more about [creating a basic build configuration file here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/create-basic-configuration).

Comment: The steps you define doesn't create a docker image so how can you add `FROM xxx:latest`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `--network=cloudbuild` to your `args` to allow the builder service account credentials to pass through to your Dockerfile steps.

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
  args: ['build', '-t', 'THE_IMAGE', '--network=cloudbuild', '.']
```

Comment: do I need to add these arguments to `cloudbuild.yaml`?

Comment: Yep, in your cloudbuild.yaml